# Как сделать такую же форму отправки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ребята,как убрать у инпутов бордеры? хотел через инпуты сделать,появились бордеры. и как отредактировать плейсхолдер(возможно ли это?) чтобы стиль был другой,как на картинке

Answer (score 1):

```css
input:focus,
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="текст" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.form {
  padding: 0 20%;
}

.form h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form h3 .red {
  color: #FA6A4C;
}


/* Стилизуем наш input */

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}


/* А Тут можно настроить стили placeholder'а */

.form input::placeholder {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <h3><span class="red">Send</span> A Message</h3>
  <label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="name">
  <label for="surname"></label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" id="surname">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Рамки можно убрать css-свойством [`border: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border).

В данном случае стоит оставить нижнюю рамку свойством [`border-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom).

Также, вероятно, стоит переопределить [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/outline) когда поле находится [в фокусе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1867c0;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
```